# Driving 3 Relays with ESP01

Tags: relay

I would like to drive 3 relays with single ESP01 pin (RX in this case). However, the ESP keeps clicking along with relays sometimes. in other times nothing happens. it doesn't work. I used the same code and wiring for single relay which works fine. So how can I drive all three relays at the same time with ESP01.
[image]

code:

```
#define PIN3 3 // Using RX as GPIO

void setup() {
  pinMode(PIN3, FUNCTION_3);   //GPIO 3 (RX) swap the pin to a GPIO.
  pinMode(PIN3, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(PIN3, LOW);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(PIN3, HIGH);
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code? Hard to debug when we don't know what you're doing. Also I do not know too much about the ESP01 in particular - is there a reason you use RXD instead of GPIO0? Seems to me a GPIO would be more fitting for this purpose.

Comment: rx is an input-only GPIO; use tx instead, and then make sure you don't use Serial.

Comment: @InBedded16 code uploaded. GPIO are needed for boot purposes which I don't want to mess with. I used this RX in multiple projects successfully.

Comment: @dandavis This is not correct. Both RX and TX can be used for either (tested).

Comment: Pins of MCU may have different purposes. You are using Pin3 as GPIO.

Comment: @motionchannel well i've not seen that `FUNCTION_3` pin mode before, maybe that matters, thanks for the nudge. Still, there's typically an LED pulled up through TX to contend with, so that complicates using TX as an input in many situations...

Answer (score 2):

You might want to wire the relays in parallel. Two relays are now directly connected to supply so they are always activated, the transistor has no control over them.

Comment: Sorry I messed the drawings. they are connected in parallel were I'm having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to use transistor with higher Hfe, or darlington transistor. In your case summary current of 3 relay coils should be bigger. It is restricted by base current multiplied by The transistor. Transistor is not saturated, it is in active mode. Not enough current to activate relay coils. Or reduce base transistor value, but not exceed max output current of MCU.